# Is there a better way to extract the n-th element of a stringstream than ignore in a loop?

Tags: c++

I want to extract the n-th element of an `std::istringstream`. Right now I'm using a loop with `std::istringstream::ignore`, something like this:

```
std::istringstream linestream(line);
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    linestream.ignore(50, ' ');    
}
linestream >> importantVariable;
```

The input is a process stat file on linux from `/proc/$PID/stat` and is comma seperated, but the fields do not have a fixed width (`std::seekg` won't work reliably here).

Is there a better way to do this? I was expecting something like an overloaded ignore method, that takes an argument which defines how many elements it should skip, instead of having to use a loop.

Edit: I've added information about the input stream.
Here is an example line:
`1092 (avahi-daemon) S 1071 1071 1071 0 -1 1077936192 30 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 534 48205824 85 18446744073709551615 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Comment: @JesperJuhl `nth_element` requires a sorted range, random access iterators and does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: What does the stream contents look like?

Comment: @0x499602D2 by the looks of it, I hazard a guess it's space-separated-anything. Would be nice to know for sure, though.

Comment: You'll want to look up (research) the definitions of *sequential access* and *random access*. Streams are sequential access.  Arrays and vectors are random access.  With sequential access, you need to fetch every item, in sequence, until you get to the item you want.

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be at least `n` tokens in the stream?

Comment: You may want to try `istream::seekg()` to set the *read pointer* to a position within the stream.  Read up on the method to see its restrictions.

Comment: Better how? If you mean efficiency, this depends a lot on what you know about the data your reading. I can guarantee that I know nothing of the data you're reading.

Comment: The short answer is: no, there isn't, this is the only way to do this.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I've added information about the stream format, should have mentioned that. @0x499602D2 the number of tokens is always the same, but the length of each token can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all said in the comments.

I just one to show an additional solution. The input data is anyway stored in a `std::string`. So you can directly extract it from there.

You can use iterators and [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead of loops.

The same works of course also for streams.

please see

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

const std::regex re(" ");


int main() {
    //                   0     1   2    3    4   5   6     7  8 9 0      1      2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  0 1 2 3  4     
    std::string line{ "1092 (avahi - daemon) S 1071 1071 1071 0 - 1 1077936192 30 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 534 48205824 "
        "85 18446744073709551615 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "};

    // 1. Extracting direcly from std::string
    std::string entry24 = *std::next(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), 24);

    std::cout << entry24 << "\n";

    // 2. Putting in Stream and extracting from stream
    // Stream solution
    std::istringstream linestream(line);
    entry24 = *std::next(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(linestream), 24);

    std::cout << entry24 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```